# Push Notifications Not Failing But Not Being Sent

Tags: php, ios, arrays, apple-push-notifications

I have set up a script to send multiple push notifications.  I call the following PHP with a POST Method from the app, with the intent of having it send a message once for each deviceToken, so I have the deviceTokens all in an array on the script.  I had it print the deviceToken so I could confirm it was correct (and it was) and my feedback when running the script said Successfully Connected To APNS, but I never receive it.  Does something look wrong here?

```
    <?php

 $deviceToken = $_POST['iostoken'];
 $deviceToken2 = $_POST['iostoken2'];
 $devices = Array();
 $devices[0] = Array();
$devices[0]["deviceToken"] = $deviceToken;
$devices[1] = Array();
$devices[1]["deviceToken"] = $deviceToken2;

$passphrase = 'passphrase';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Test message';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
foreach($devices as $device){
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $devices["deviceToken"]) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you have your certs set up correctly? I've had issues before with the certs not being re-generated once I added Push Notifications to it

Comment: @LyricalPanda.  Yes.  I altered the code to attempt just one device token (the same one the printout showed me it was trying in the above code), and it delivered the push successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the following lines

```
$deviceToken = $_POST['iostoken'];
$deviceToken2 = $_POST['iostoken2'];
$devices = Array();
$devices[0] = Array();
$devices[0]["deviceToken"] = $deviceToken;
$devices[1] = Array();
$devices[1]["deviceToken"] = $deviceToken2;
```

to

```
$devices = array($_POST['iostoken'], $_POST['iostoken2']);
```

then you have a mistake in your loop, on the play load , you should use `device` not `devices`

```
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $device) 
              . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that, and thanks for the advice on simplifying the array.